# PyCharm confirmation before running a code under debug

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2020.2.3 and unknowingly I have clicked the check box in the below figure

[image]

Now, even if my code is in the middle of debugging, hitting run would terminate the debug and begin running the code. How do I restore it to being unchecked? Thanks.

PS: My "allow parallel run" setting is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: In the run config uncheck "allow parallel run".

Comment: @bobah it is already unchecked as shown in the second image. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't find it, Worst case scenario, remove the .idea folder and open again the project (it will reset all pycharm setting for this project)

Comment: @DoriAviram tried that, no dialog box still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete this line:

```
    <property name="restartRequiresConfirmation" value="false" />
```

from `.idea\workspace.xml`, or just change `false` to `true`.

Comment: The option doesn't exist anymore, how can I find it?

Comment: @Hakaishin Thanks for pointing this out. In `Settings` > `Advanced Settings` in section `Run/Debug` there is a `Confirm rerun with process termination` checkbox that seems to control this setting.